ISPF Edit dynamic detection if data is EBCDIC, ASCII, UTF-8, or Binary?
With git having the ability to manage data as EBCDIC, ASCII, UTF-8, Binary, or ... on z/OS and with the ability to have some of that data stored in z/OS datasets (PS/PDS/PDSE), is there a way to dynamically determine the encoding of the data?
The ISPF statistics don't help (no surprise).
I presume one would have to read the data and if so what, if any, is a fool proof way to determine the encoding?

There are indications here that PDSE members can have a CCSID in their extended attributes.  Alternatively, if you scroll down the answers to this question there are indications that heuristics exist and code implementing them is available.

The comment about CCSID's in PDSE is that they 'could' be added but presently they aren't - at least they are not part of the ISPF statistics part of the PDSE directory entry. Anything can be added to the PDSE directory entry by the code that created the entry and that would be a nice addition if/when IBM adds it.
